# For-loop not working till the specified input

Tags: javascript, for-loop

The loop in myFunctionlp, is not working to the specified user input through prompt which is round in this case. I want that loop to run until the input of the user which I am getting through prompt. myFunctionlp is being called by a button press.

```js
var round = prompt("Enter number of rounds");
var defaultNumberOfRounds = 1;
var roundno = isNaN(Number(round)) ? defaultNumberOfRounds : round;
var images_arr = ["../img/paper.png", "../img/stone.png",
  "../img/sisor.png"
];
var size = images_arr.length;
console.log(`round: ${round}, roundno: ${roundno}`);

function myFunctionlp() {
  for (var i = 0; i < roundno; i++) { //this loop
    console.log(i);

    setInterval(function() {
      var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
      $('#random').attr('src', images_arr[x]); // JQuery
    }, 1500);

    setInterval(function() {
      var sound = new Audio("../audio/audio.mp3");
      sound.play();
      if (s == 50) {
        sound.pause();
      } else {
        alert("Hello");
      }
    }, 3000);


  }
}

function stop() {
  for (s = 0; s < 51; s++) {
    console.log(s);
  }
}

function extra() {
  var music = new Audio("../audio/audio_3.mp3");
  music.play();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="onClick" onclick="myFunctionlp()">Play</button>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please click edit, then scroll down and click edit above snippet and add relevant HTML and frameworks - also `s` is not defined

Comment: Thanks, mpluyngjan for helping me out.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do.  stop is never called, so s never reaches 50.  setInterval returns immediately, so for round you are creating two intervals for every round immediately.  So if rounds is 50 you have 150 calls to playing sound and random images running every 3 seconds.  Need to clarify what you aretrying to do